# Unexpected terminal behavior after SSH session ends unexpectedly

Tags: bash, terminal, mouse

I am regularly experiencing an unexpected behavior in my terminal, with the following sequence:

1. connection to a remote server
2. usage of a command/software that will be embedeed in the terminal (text editor, top...)
3. session ends unexpectedly
4. any mouse interaction injects unexpected characters in the terminal (and it is impossible to select, copy'n'paste, and so on); for example:

- just clicking:

```bash
0;129;19M
```

- selecting:

```bash
0;48;37M0;73;38m
```

So my question is two-fold:

1. what is causing this behavior (the root cause)?
2. how to circumvent this?

Comment: Try running `reset` and/or `stty sane` to maybe save your terminal.

Comment: The application enables mouse reporting mode and the terminal stays in that mode. `reset` should fix it, `stty` is irrelevant. What you could do, and in my opinion all Unix systems and Linux distributions should do by default, is to begin your prompt with some "soft reset" escape sequences that clear modes like this.

Comment: @egmont what would that be? I tried to include `$(stty sane)` at the beginning of my `PS1`, it is not sufficient. Using `tput rs1` as the same effect as `reset`; it does the trick but is not usable outside of this peculiar problem (it clears the terminal)

Comment: @MBR Soft reset escape sequence is `ESC` `[` `!` `p`, therefore you should try to place `\[\e[!p\]` in `bash`'s `PS1` (see the PROMPTING section in its manual for `\[` `\]`, these tell `bash` that the characters in between don't advance the cursor).

Comment: `\e[1000l` did the trick; `\[\e[!p\]` was unfortunately not enough. Thank you for your help @ChrisDavies & @egmont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ESC [?1000l` to disable mouse events:

```
printf '\e[?1000l'
```

The reason you need to do this is because the application enabled mouse events but was unable to disable them in the normal manner ("*session ends unexpectedly*").

References

- [How to get MouseMove and MouseClick in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970472/2344631) on StackOverflow
- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf) (PDF)